# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{n+1}}{(2+i-z)^{n}}$ in function of the parameter $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I have to examine the behaviour of the following series in function of the parameter $z\in \mathbb{C}$: $\space$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{n+1}}{(2+i-z)^{n}}$ $\space$

---

I have no idea how to do this... I even don't know how to start with it... I know that I can use the absolut convergence or the cauchy criterion but I don't know what to do with them in this case... Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is a geometric series and it is convergent if and only if $$\left|\frac{2}{2+i-z}\right|<1$$

Comment: Okey, I understand what you say but now, how can I know in which geometric zone is it convergent? I mean, if I try to solve that inequation, I reach to the conclusion that if $2+i-z>0$ it is convergent if $z>-i$ but can I compare $z$ and $i$ ?

Comment: @User160 Your inequalities don't make sense. There are no inequalities for complex numbers.